# Django model ManyToManyField.add is not working

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model named `TopicRoom` and it has a field called `creator` which is a foreign key to the user model. And a many to many field called `members` which is a many to many rel to the user model

```py
@receiver(post_save, sender=models.TopicRoom)
def add_topic_room_creator_as_a_member(instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        print("added creator", instance.creator, instance)
        instance.members.add(instance.creator)
        print(instance.members.all())
```

When I create a new instance in the admin panel it prints this

```
added creator bob@gmail.com TopicRoom object (24)
<QuerySet [<User: bob@gmail.com>]>
```

but when I view the model in the admin panel it shows that there are no members.
And when I retrieve the model from the django manage.py shell, that also shows that there are no members for that object instance

```py
>>> TopicRoom.objects.get(id=24).members.all()
<QuerySet []>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very common issue with `post_save` Django signals depending on how you are handling data and data structures.

But the good thing is this can be solved easily using `transaction.on_commit()` method. [Ref: Performing actions after commit](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/db/transactions/#performing-actions-after-commit)

Update your `add_topic_room_creator_as_a_member` function like this:

```
from django.db import transaction
@receiver(post_save, sender=models.TopicRoom)
def add_topic_room_creator_as_a_member(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        def add_member():
            instance.members.add(instance.creator)
            print(instance.members.all())

        transaction.on_commit(add_member)
```

`transaction.on_commit` makes sure your function runs after the successful completion of the current transaction.

Answer (score -1):

Try using:

```
instance.save()
```

after

```
print(instance.members.all())
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you set relative names for both fields? because Django creates a default relative name "model_set. In your case, you are using the User model two times.